# how send in html value of php to server?

Tags: php, html

I try send value of input to the server, but in server I receive NULL of variable front side:

```
<form method="POST" action="validationUploadEmployee.php" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
  <div class="container">

    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter ID"  name="idW" value = '<?php echo "$idW"; ?>'    disabled="disabled" required >

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Full Name"  name="name" value = '<?php echo "$nameE"; ?>' required>

    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" value='<?php echo "$emailE"; ?>  

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" value='<?php echo "$passwordE"; ?>' maxlength="10" size="8" required>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-rpt" value='<?php echo "$passwordE"; ?>' maxlength="10" size="8" required>

    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number Phone"  name="phone" value='<?php echo "$phoneE"; ?>'  required>

    <input type="text" placeholder=""  name="branch" value='<?php echo "$myBranch"; ?>'   disabled="disabled" required>
```

server side I receive variable like that:

```
$idW=$_POST['idW'];//id worker
```

Thank you.

Comment: on validationUploadEmployee.php are you using for example, $_POST['name'] to get the value of the name? Also note disabled fields won't send via POST. They're literally disabled.

Comment: yes, example:-$idW=$_POST['idW'];//id worker
$name=$_POST["name"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$psw = $_POST["psw"];
$psw_rpt = $_POST["psw-rpt"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$branch = $_POST["branch"];
$_SESSION["idW"] = $idW;//to return for full the inputs in editEmployee.php

Comment: disabled inputs are not posted

Comment: If you want an input that the user can't edit, but still submitted to the server, use `readonly`, not `disabled`.